# SSRS Exporiting to excel

Tags: reporting-services

Iam desing A Report in ssrs and Set Header ,footer and body images for report,Then i click on export to pdf its working fine,but Export excel Header and footer images are not display,Please help me

Answer (score 2):

This is due to export limitation of reporting services to excel

From  MSDN

> Page footers are rendered in the Excel footer section.
>
> Because of Excel limitations, text boxes are the only type of report
>   item that can be rendered in the Excel header/footer section.

More info at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd255234.aspx#PageHeadersFooters

Answer (score 0):

I have tried in SSRS 2005,2008 and 2008 R2 it is working every version for header, not for footer.
When we export to excel header part will be displayed but footer part will not be displayed.